# Unit of measure for image dimensions in AsciiDoc/AsciiDoctor documents

Tags: image, pdf, asciidoctor

There is no indication neither in the docs nor on first three pages of Google search results about what is the unit of measure of the images in AsciiDoc documents. This is significant topic, because AsciiDoc converts both to HTML (native unit is pixel) and to PDF (native unit is either cm or pt).

So, can someone answer and/or add a section to documentation about the following:

- When I write `image::path/to/image.png["Caption",300,200]`, what is those `300` and `200`? Pixels?
- When I produce a PDF from the AsciiDoc document, what DPI it uses, if we are using pixels? Can I control it in some configuration setting?
- If those dimensions are in some abstract units, then, what is the widths of HTML and PDF pages in those units?
- Is there any way to make output-agnostic AsciiDoc document with images? I don't want pixel-perfect identical  layout in both formats, but it would be great to preserve the relative sizes of images at least.

I am using `asciidoctor -b html` for HTML output and `asciidoctor-fopub` for PDF. I will not use `asciidoctor-pdf` until it'll support at least the same feature set as fopub.

Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For html, it's pixels: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/blob/master/lib/asciidoctor/converter/html5.rb#L520-L523

For pdf, I'm not really sure, but it probably depends on Apache FOP, as that's what's being used. The [xslt](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-fopub/blob/master/src/dist/docbook-xsl/fo-pdf.xsl#L427-L455) seems to indicate inches without any scaling. You'll have to dig into that whole mess to actually figure out what's being used and how to modify it.

Comment: I am so grateful to you that you investigated the sources for me... After some thinking I just threw away about HTML compatibility, checked that the PDF page width is around 450 those unknown units and changed width of all images relative to this reference width.